# Minimizing t-statistic

Tags: matlab, optimization, statistics

Consider 2 data sets, `A = {100 x 7}` and `B = {300 x 7}`

I would like do something like the following:

I want to find `C` which minimizes `t = tstat.stats`.

```
C=B(randperm(100),:);
ttest2(C,A);
t = tstat.stats;
```

Comment: If `randperm` refers to Matlab's function, your syntax if wrong. If it's a variable, define it so that we can run your code

Comment: Sorry about that. I just meant a random selection of rows.